# window.parent jQuery selector not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

This code below works fine

```
$('html').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    window.parent.scrollBy(-120 * delta,0);
    return false;
});
```

but this one doesn't, can anyone tell me why. I'd love to know.

```
$(window.parent).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    window.parent.scrollBy(-120 * delta,0);
    return false;
});
```

I'd like to clarify that the `window` selector doesn't work in this case either.

Comment: i decided to just use the working version, if you have a working code why question why the not working version is faulty?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that jQuery's event handler wrapper must use `window.event` to retrieve the current event in IE. If you set a handler from window A on an event in window B, the script in window A will be looking at window A's `window.event`, whilst the event is actually occurring on window B.

But there may be more issues than that, too. Cross-window/frame scripting is fraught with difficulties and jQuery is not particularly designed to work around them. To make jQuery work properly cross-frame you will generally need an instance of jQuery in both windows, and you should only use the corresponding instance of jQuery ($) to interact with each window.

**eta re comment:**

OK, having looked into `mousewheel` further, I don't know how your code can be working in Firefox (it certainly doesn't for me). Firefox doesn't support `mousewheel` events at all; instead it supports `DOMMouseScroll` events. Also for the other browsers that support `mousewheel`, it should be bound to a DOM Node rather than the window. So I guess what you're looking for is:

```
if ('MouseScrollEvent' in window) {
    $(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
        return scroll(event.detail*-40);
    });
} else {
    $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
        return scroll(event.wheelDelta);
    });
}

function scroll(d) {
    window.scrollBy(-d, 0);
    return false;
};
```

(However in WebKit this will stop scrolling when the mouse moves out of the horizontal area corresponding to the viewport width. You may prefer to bind the events to the wider element like the div, if it fills the browser.)

Comment: hi bobice, there is only one window in this case and i tried "window.event" instead of "event" in the handler, yet it produces only syntax errors, both in dreamweaver and IE8.

Comment: If there is only one window, why are you accessing `window.parent`?

Comment: Anyhow, the delta property would normally be accessed as `event.wheelDelta`. But if you have syntax errors you aren't even getting that far!

Comment: bobince could you please look at the code i've included in the question above, is it what you inferring. That code gives me syntax errors right after i ad the .wheelDelta  
thank you

Comment: You don't put the property access in the function argument list. It should be `function(event) {`...`window.scrollBy(event.wheelDelta*-120, 0);`.

Comment: thank you, that is correct. I'm not at all familiar with jQuery actually. Though through trial and error practices i believe it is the selector itself that is not working right in IE8. I've made a jsbin page for the complete code. http://jsbin.com/anado which doesn't work in IE8 but works in firefox.